# when I built my first dependency injected class in Laravel 5.3 I got a BindingResolutionException

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5.3

Here is my code:

```
class WechatServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    // Bootstrap the application services.
    // @return void
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    // Register the application services.
    // @return void
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('App\Http\Wechat',function()
        {
            $arr = array('token'=>'foo') ;
            return new Wechat($arr) ;
        });
    }
}
```

try to auto inject the dependency here

```
class WechatController extends Controller
{
    protected $wechatObj;

    public function __construct(Wechat $wechatObj)
    {
        $this->wechatObj = $wechatObj;
    }
    ...
}
```

in App\Http\Wechat.php

```
public function __construct($options)
{
    $this->token = isset($options['token'])?$options['token']:'';
    $this->encodingAesKey = isset($options['encodingaeskey'])?$options['encodingaeskey']:'';
    $this->appid = isset($options['appid'])?$options['appid']:'';
    $this->appsecret = isset($options['appsecret'])?$options['appsecret']:'';
    $this->agentid = isset($options['agentid'])?$options['agentid']:'';
    $this->debug = isset($options['debug'])?$options['debug']:false;
    $this->logcallback = isset($options['logcallback'])?$options['logcallback']:false;
}
```

the error stack

- **BindingResolutionException** in Container.php line 850:
  Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [  $options ]] in class App\Http\Wechat
- in Container.php line 850
- at Container->resolveNonClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 817
- at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 790

Comment: I think you need to run a `composer dump-autoload` here

Answer (score 1):

All of the steps are done perfectly, however you need to register your service provider too in `config/app.php` under the `providers` array:

```
'providers' => [
    // .. others
    WechatServiceProvider::class,
],
```